# Laravel redirect() to is not generating the correct url

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5, model, crud

I would like to start by apologizing for the newbish question.

I'm in the process of making a simple CRUD controller on Laravel.

My create method is as follows:

```
 public function create(Request $request)
{
    $dummy = new Dummy();
    $dummy->title = $request->title;
    $dummy->content = $request->dummy_content;
    $dummy->created_at = new \DateTime();
    $dummy->updated_at = new \DateTime();
    $dummy->save();

    return redirect()
        ->route('index/view/', ['id' => $dummy->id])
        ->with('message', 'Dummy created successfully');
}
```

my view method:

```
public function view($id)
{

    $dummy = Dummy::find($id);

    return view('index/view', [
        'dummy' => $dummy
    ]);
}
```

my corresponding routes:

```
Route::get('index/view/{id}', 'IndexController@view');
Route::post('index/create', 'IndexController@create');
```

and my form:

```
<form action="create" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="content">Content</label>
        <textarea name="dummy_content"  cols="80" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I submit my form I get the following exception:

> InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 314:
>   Route [index/view/] not defined.

I've been stuck here for quite some time and I still can't figure out why I'm not generating my route properly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a route when instead you should call the controller. This will do the trick

```
 return redirect()->action('IndexController@view', ['id' => $id])->with($stuff);
```

Also, i suggest you to define aliases to routes, so you could do something like

In your controller:

```
 return Redirect::route('route_alias', ['id' => $id])->with($stuff);
```

In your routes:

```
Route::get('/index/view/{id}', [
        'as' => 'route_alias',
        'uses' => 'IndexController@view'
    ]);
```